# adding multipe new columns in rails migration using block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any better way to add new columns to rails table than this way

```
class AddColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
    add_column :users, :contact1, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact2, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact3, :decimal
    add_column :users, :contact4, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact5, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact6, :string
    add_column :users, :contact7, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact8, :integer
    add_column :users, :contact9, :integer
  end
end
```

Can we use change_table method and write these inside a block? instead of repeating the add_column again and again

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple columns to a same table  like this

```
def change
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to dry, then you can write in following manner also,

```
{
  string: [:first_name, :last_name, :contact6],
  integer: [:contact1 ,:contact2 ,:contact4 ,:contact5 ,:contact7 ,:contact8 ,:contact9],
  decimal: [:contact3] 
}.each do |type, columns| 
  columns.each { |col| add_column :users, col, type }
end
```

Comment: I'd stick to the way the OP wrote his migration or use Sumanth Madishetty's suggestion. I don't recommend trying to be too clever in your migrations.